# Capture string in Linux while doing a ping

Tags: python, linux, find, ping

I try to find specific string while doing a ping. In windows, I can do that simply by using command:

```
ping localhost | find "time"
```

But, when I do this command in Linux, it returns: find : 'time' : No such file or directory.
I am making a program that can run both in linux and windows using python. Why i want to find 'time' in ping output is because the errorlevel always return '0' even if the destination host unreachable (in windows). Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grep , not find :

```
ping localhost | grep "time"
```

find it used to find files , not strings